# ORACLE server session terminated by fatal error

Tags: oracle, triggers, oracle11g, ora-00600

I have edited a `Trigger` and try to save. then i got below error.

```
Error: ORA-00603: ORACLE server session terminated by fatal error
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [kqlidchg1], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-00001: unique constraint (SYS.I_PLSCOPE_SIG_IDENTIFIER$) violated
```

i can't save my `trigger` with modifications. how can i solve this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ORA-00600 is a generic Oracle message indicating an unhandled side-effect of your action i.e. an Oracle bug.  The precise reason for the bug may be dependent on the database version, patch level and platform (OS flavour and version).

The proper way of dealing with these things is to contact Oracle Support.  If you don't have a Support contract you're probably out of luck.  The nature of ORA-00600 means that some of them hit very specific sites, so maybe nobody else has had this before.  But try Google, you never know...

---

And lo!  Google serves up [this gem by Marc Tempel](http://logbuffer.wordpress.com/2011/10/19/oracle-ora-0600-on-creating-trigger-on-11-2/).  Perhaps it will help you.

Comment: +1 on Googling, in this case on "SYS.I_PLSCOPE_SIG_IDENTIFIER$" yields this [solution](http://www.db-eccentric.com/2011/04/ora-0600-type-of-day.html)

Comment: @Colin'tHart - I googled for `ORA-00600+kqlidchg1`   My hit references your hit :)

Answer (score 8):

I repeatedly got this error list creating a Trigger:

```
ORA-00603: ORACLE server session terminated by fatal error
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [kqlidchg1], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], 
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-00001: unique constraint (SYS.I_PLSCOPE_SIG_IDENTIFIER$) violated
00603. 00000 -  "ORACLE server session terminated by fatal error"
```

In SQLDeveloper, edit the PLSCOPE_SETTINGS:

```
Tools->Preferences ->Database->PL/SQL Compiler
```

Set "PLScope identifiers:" to "None"
This fixed the problem and I had no issues after this.